# Atomic compound statement works different in Db2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

When issuing the following statement, it prints the modified rows with Atomic, but not without it. However, I haven't found something in the documentation that explains this behavior.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
 
drop table mytable@
 
CREATE TABLE mytable (
col1 INTEGER
) @

SELECT * FROM new TABLE (INSERT INTO mytable (col1) VALUES (1)) @
SELECT * FROM mytable @

BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT col1 FROM new TABLE (INSERT INTO mytable (col1) VALUES (2));
END @
SELECT * FROM mytable @

BEGIN
 SELECT col1 FROM new TABLE (INSERT INTO mytable (col1) VALUES (3));
END @
```

I got this output:

[image]

Comment: `BEGIN ATOMIC` doesn't print anything according to your example. The output rows are printed by the subsequent select statement. The `BEGIN ATOMIC` statement prints just info on successful completion instead of expected failure as for `BEGIN NOT ATOMIC` (the last statement).

Comment: @MarkBarinstein is  AngocA asking why the SQL0104N happens in one case, but not the other (given the SELECT statement is not useful in either case) ?

Comment: @mao The original statement was: "it prints the modified rows with Atomic". But it doesn't print any rows in any compound (atomic or not atomic) statement. The only strange behavior for me here is, that it really doesn't return SQL0104N on a select statement in the inlined (atomic) compound statement. Seems, that it's some undocumented "feature" of db2 (not only CLP). It's may be really useful for such selects from a data-change operation. Some sort of output to /dev/null.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein . The inconsistency between ATOMIC / NOT ATOMIC in this case is a concern, because it seems natural to expect the same result from both cases. But the behaviour seems to be that the ATOMIC case is somehow handling the exception and suppressing it, while the NOT ATOMIC case does not handle the exception and correctly throws it.

Comment: maybe one to ask IBM Support